# Find the original pdf given conditions in order to find Maximum Likelihood Estimator

Tags: statistics

Random Sample Distribution from $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$.

Given the p.d.f of $f(x;\theta)$

Find the Maximum Likelihood Estimator $\theta$;

When $\theta = 0$, $f(x;\theta) = 1$ where $0<x<1$. When $\theta=1$, $f(x;\theta) = \frac{1}{{2}\sqrt{x}}$ where $0 < x < 1$.

I am having trouble finding the equation of this statement. Originally, the pdf is not given. But, probably wrong, I THINK the equation is

$$f(x;\theta) = \frac{1}{2^\theta}x^{-\theta/2}$$

However, if this is the equation, the maximum likelihood I calculated turns out to be $0$. I find this really strange.

Could someone give some advice of how I could find the original pdf given those conditions so that I can solve the MLE?

Comment: I've answered the question, explaining the likelihood function, which I hope helps. By the way I think there's a slight error in your post for $\theta=1$: it should be $\frac1{2\sqrt{x}}$.

Comment: I've amended my answer after your edit, but I'm still not sure it's helping you. I really don't understand how you could be asked to find the maximum likelihood estimator without knowing the pdf (or being told the name of the distribution, which is equivalent).

Answer (score 0):

> Could someone give some advice of how I could find the original pdf given those conditions so that I can solve the MLE?

You can't. In general, a probability density has to be non-negative and sum to 1. So given any non-negative function $g(x)$, you can convert it to a probability density by dividing it by its sum over the range of $x$. Put

$$c = \int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)\;dx$$

Then

$$ f(x) = \frac{1}{c}g(x) $$

is a probability density because it's non zero and its sum is $\frac{1}{c} \int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)\;dx = \frac{1}{c}c = 1$.

$g(x)$ is known as the core. Your two conditions when $\theta=0$, $f(x;\theta)=1$, and when $\theta=1$, $f(x;\theta)=1/(2\sqrt{x})$, where $0<x<1$, aren't sufficient to determine $g(x)$.

In any case,

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1 f(x;\theta) \;dx
&= \frac{1}{2^\theta} \int_0^1 x^{-\theta/2} \;dx\\
&= \frac{1}{2^\theta} \times \frac{2}{2-\theta}\left[ x^{1-\theta/2}\right]_0^1,\;\;\;\theta\neq2\\
&= \frac{1}{2^{\theta-1}(2-\theta)}
\end{align}$$

This is equal to $1$ for $\theta=0$ and $\theta=1$ but isn't equal to 1 in general, so $f(x;\theta)$ isn't, in general, a probability density.

Comment: $$f(x;\theta) = \frac{1}{2^\theta}x^{-\theta/2}\;\;\;\text{where }0 < x < 1$$

This is not actually the pdf given. I just guessed that it would be this equation. So does that mean in this case it would be L(θ) = 1 x 1/(2√x)?

Comment: Well I still don't have any idea how to solve this problem, but I did learn something else that helped me with another question so its still worth it. I am still stuck with this question though